# Symfony2 template variables from several classes

Tags: php, events, symfony, listener

I need to pass variables to template from two places:

1. Normal controller's method, eg:

   ```
   class ProductsController extends Controller
   {
       /**
        * Products
        * @Route("", name="products")
        * @Template
        */
       public function productsAction()
       {
           return array('var1' => 'sth', 'var2' => 'etc);
       }
   ```
2. Bootstrap controller (listener triggered by **kernel.controller** event)

   ```
   class BeforeControllerListener
   {
       public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
       {
           // @some_vars
       }
   ```

How can I inject `@some_vars` from listener to template? Vars in both methods aren't static, so global variables aren't the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onKernelController()` do:

```
$event->getRequest()->attributes->add(array('someVar' => 'someValue'));
```

In your `productsAction()` do:

```
$request->attributes->get('someVar');
```

Cheers ;)